# Elegant way to pass along parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application that has a feature for generate reports.

Before producing the report, the user is presented with a form to specify the date range for the report,

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :generate_report}, :multipart => true) do %>

    <h3>Date range is inclusive</h3>

    <b>Start Date</b><br />
    <%= date_select :range, :startDate, options = {:order => [:day, :month, :year]} %

    <b>End Date</b><br />
    <%= date_select :range, :endDate, options = {:order => [:day, :month, :year]} %>

    <%= submit_tag "Generate Report", :disable_with => 'Reporting...' %>

<% end %>
```

The supporting code then generates the report,

```
# GET /sales_activities/generate_report
def generate_report

    @start_date = Date.civil(params[:range][:"startDate(1i)"].to_i,params[:range][:"startDate(2i)"].to_i,params[:range][:"startDate(3i)"].to_i)
    @end_date   = Date.civil(params[:range][:"endDate(1i)"].to_i,params[:range][:"endDate(2i)"].to_i,params[:range][:"endDate(3i)"].to_i)

    @end_date_inclusive = @end_date + 1.day

    @sales = SalesActivity.find(:all,
                 :select => [:salesperson_id],
                 :conditions => {:created_at => @start_date..@end_date_inclusive, :code => [5]},
                 :group => :salesperson_id)

    # <Skip the boring code>

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml  => @report }
      format.json { render :json => @report }
    end
  end
```

And then the view is rendered in the usual way.  If the user likes what they see, they then have the option to export the report as csv.

I currently have the following code to pass the specified range to the method that generates the same report for export, but it doesn't seem very, errrr, good, and results in long urls.

```
<h2>Regulatory Report</h2>

<h4>Reporting Period from <%= @start_date.strftime('%d/%m/%y') %> to <%= @end_date.strftime('%d/%m/%y') %></h4>

  <%= link_to image_tag("Buttons/ExportReport.png", :border => 0), report_export_sales_activities_path(:start_date_str => @start_date, :end_date_str => @end_date) %>
```

My question is, is there a better way to pass on these parameters to the export method? Thank you.

Comment: Using a POST request would keep your parameters out of the URL and shorten it up a bit. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

AR will let you use the params format generated by the date_select helper directly

```
@sales = SalesActivity.where(['(created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:range][:start_date], params[:range][:end_date]])
```